# Under the transformation $ w=\sqrt \frac{1-iz}{z-i}$,

Tags: complex-analysis

Under the transformation $\displaystyle w=\sqrt \frac{1-iz}{z-i}$, the region $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|\leq1\}$ is transformed to

> $1).\displaystyle \{z \in \mathbb{C} :0< arg (z)< \pi\}$
>
> $2).\displaystyle\{z \in \mathbb{C} :-\pi< arg (z)< 0\}$
>
> $3).\displaystyle \{z \in \mathbb{C} :0< arg (z)< \frac{\pi}{2} 
> \;or \;  \pi< arg (z)< \frac{3\pi}{2}\
> \}$
>
> $4).\displaystyle\{z \in \mathbb{C} :\frac{\pi}{2} < arg (z)< \pi\;\;or\;{\frac{3\pi}{2} :< arg (z)< 2\pi\}
> }$

As i try to solve the question by taking random value of $z$  let take $z=0$ ,thus after the calculation i get $w=\sqrt i$ ,whose principal value i calculated and got $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$
 so the answer can be $1$ or $3$ but further i don't have idea how to solve ,because if i try for another value of $z$ calculations becomes bit tricky

Please help

Thank you

Comment: In 3 there is misprint. Must be $\pi<\text{arg}z<\frac{3\pi}{2}$, and 3 -- is the right answer.

Comment: I checked it in real paper and you are correct ,can you please tell me how to think about this question?

Comment: Express $z$ in terms of $w$ (i.e. as a function $z(w)$ in $w$) and then use the inequality $|z(w)|\leq 1$ to figure out the region.

Comment: @GoranMalic This will be very lengthy and difficult to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $w_1=\dfrac{1-iz}{z-i}$. Since the pole $i\in\partial G$, then the image of $\partial G$ -- is straight line. We'll find her by two points: since $w_1(1)=1$, $w_1(-1)=-1$, then $w_1(\partial G)=\mathbb{R}$. Since $w_1(0)=i$, then $w_1(G)$ is upper half plane. Here is $|w_1|>0$ and $0<\text {arg}w_1<\pi$

Now consider $w=\sqrt {w_1}$. We need to find the image of upper half plane. But we know that $\sqrt{w_1}=\sqrt{|w_1|}e^{i\frac{{arg}w_1+2\pi k}{2}}$, $k=0,1$. All that's left is view possible values of fraction $\displaystyle\frac{{arg}w_1+2\pi k}{2}$.

Comment: +1 for such a beautiful explanation.

Comment: I fixed some misprints in the answer.